# Объявление переменной

Tags: java, переменные

Всем доброго времени суток)) 
Объясните что здесь за магия?)

```
public class Game {

    private static final String GAME_NAME = "XO";

    private Player[] players;

    public String getGameName() {
        return GAME_NAME;
}
```

и есть класс

```
public class ConsoleView {

    private final Game game;

    public ConsoleView(final Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void showGameName() {
        System.out.println(game.getGameName());
    }
}
```

Так вот, не пойму что это за объявление поля такое?

```
private final Game game;
```

И я не могу через `Game` вызывать методы, а только через `game`.

Comment: Выглядит как плохой дизайн класса Game. По логике поле GAME_NAME  не должно быть статическим, так как каждый объект этого класса может иметь собственное название. В противном случае и метод доступа к названию следовало бы сделать так же статическим, не зависящим от конкретного объекта.

Answer (score 3):

Ключевое слово `final` по отношению к полям класса означает неизменяемость этого поля. То есть, после вызова:

```
public ConsoleView(final Game game) {
    this.game = game;
}
```

Вы уже не сможете заменить объект `game` на другой объект (но поменять его *состояние* сможете).

> И я не могу через Game вызывать методы, а только через game

Так как метод `getGameName()` класса `Game` не является статическим, то он может быть вызван только через экземпляр данного класса. Чтобы вызвать этот метод через `Game` Вам необходимо объявить его как `static`:

```
public static String getGameName() {
    return GAME_NAME;
}
```

Comment: следует различать объявление поля как final, и параметр в методе. В методе это лишь подсказка компилятору.

Comment: @post_zeew как понимать вот эту запись - "Game game"???

Comment: @ДашаНовикова, Это объявление объекта `game` класса `Game`.

Comment: @post_zeew а почему не так Game game = new Game(); В чем отличие?

Comment: @ДашаНовикова Отличия практически нет. Если переменным не задавать никакое значение ("int a; Object o; Game game"), то это за вас сделает контруктор вашего класса - ссылочные типы будут null, а примитивы будут принимать 0, false и т.д. Но в данном случае вы задаете переменной game значение, которое передаете в параметре этого самого конструктора

Comment: @ДашаНовикова, В строке `Game game;` Вы просто **объявляете** переменную `game` типа `Game` (и **не создаете** какой-либо объект). В строке `Game game = new Game();` Вы объявляете переменную `game` типа `Game` и **создаете экземпляр класса** `Game`.

Comment: @post_zeew  а как тогда вызываются методы другого класса через game.getGameName(), если я не создаю никакого экземпляра??

Comment: @ДашаНовикова, Не понял вопроса.

Comment: @post_zeew ну я же в коде нигде явно не пишу **Game game = new Game(); **  а вызвать метод этого класса могу **game.getGameName()**

Comment: @ДашаНовикова, У Вас в конструктор класса `ConsoleView` передается **уже ранее созданный** объект `game`.